# How to make sure ftp stream is fully download?

Tags: node.js, promise, stream, ftp

This is my code

```
const execute = async() => {
  const dir = `c://users/xxx/desktop/test/`
  const ftp = new PromiseFtp()
  try {
    await ftp.connect(config)
    for (let word of word_name) {
      let lists = await ftp.list(`/loc/${word}/`)
      let file = lists.slice(-2)[0] //get recent file
      let file_path = `${dir}${file.name}`
      const stream = await ftp.get(`/loc/${word}/${file.name}`)
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.once('end', resolve)
        stream.once('error', reject)
        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file_path))
      })
      let byte = fs.readFileSync(file_path )
      byte = iconv.decode(byte, 'big5')
      console.log(byte)
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    return ftp.end()
  }
}
```

I use `promise-ftp` module, sometimes the `byte` in the loop all return correct value，but sometimes one or more than one value just return `undefined`，I think the reason is asynchronous stream, I tried use `stream.once('finish')`and other way，but it not working too，anyone can explain why? thanks。

Comment: Does the download work with a single hardcoded file?  And what is variable `word_name`? And you have double `//` in your `dir`.

Comment: `word_name` is an array, it contain four foldername and it can help me build my remote path name, eg: `/loc/${word}/` become `/loc/1110215/`. `dir` i edited, just a dummy word. and yes, the four download file are hardcoded file, they have same format but different value.

Comment: `var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./output'); writeStream.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });`  Did you try to log the error when you write steam in the file?

Comment: my log did not show error, so i am confuse.. this is i try using your advice, ihave a question, is this code right?  `var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(file_path)
      stream.pipe(writeStream)`

Comment: @kennyname, yes. it is correct. Would that be the issue of the resource of ftp? Are you sure the resource is all right?

Comment: @ikhvjs, i sure the resource is fine, because sometimes my code can get the right data, sometimes first and second data is fine and third and four data is `undefined`,  but sometimes this situation is oppsited... so i sure the remote resource are fine.

Comment: @kennyname, that doesn't really prove the resource is fine. I would try to use some tool like `sftp` or `filezilla` to try to get the file from the ftp server for those records resulting `undefined`.

Comment: I think this is kind of bug or something, I found a issue that had the same problem as me but not solved on GitHub.

Comment: @kennyname, could you share the issue? It may help people in the future.

Comment: [Link here](https://github.com/realtymaps/promise-ftp/issues/30), I change my lib,use basic-ftp to avoid this problem, the node-ftp module have the same issue too.